# Business Data Catalog does not appear in SSP admin

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to connect to a database (SQL Server 2005) in MOSS 2007 using BDC. I've created the aplication definition xml and I need to import it in Sharepoint shared services provider in order to use it.

The problem is I cannot find the Business Data Catalog (where "Import application definition" is) section in SSP admin. Here is a screenshot with what appears in my shared services admin:

http://imageshack.us/f/17/screenbf.png/

Can someone please help me with this? Why can't I see that BDC section? If you need more details, ask :) Thank you.

LATER EDIT: I've searched a little more and it seems that BDC is a MOSS enterprise only feature. Can someone please confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed this. The problem was that BDC is a MOSS enterprise only feature (ugh). So I installed an enterprise license (all the software is installed in sharepoint, only that certain features are hidden depending on your license... yuck, I hate this).

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not provide the image path. Are you trying to set BDC as datasource for User Profiles. If you have confusion and want to learn about BDC then [Follow this article](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-bdc-part-1-of-8) 
and others similar to it provided there.

Comment: I have followed that article before and the problem I'm facing is related to part 2, near the end, at the "Loading the ADF into MOSS" section.

When I try to import the xml into SSP, as said in the article, quote "To get there from Central Administration, click on your SSP name in the Quick Launch menu on the left, then click Import application definition in the Business Data Catalog section. ". 

I do not see the BDC section